# Where should I put the index?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

This is pseudo-code:

```
Select 
    count(score) 
from 
   myTable
join 
   HisTable on myTAble.id = HisTable.id 
where 
   name='aaa'
group by 
   id 
having 
   count(score) > 3 
order by 
   (someField)
```

My question is about index. Where should I put the non-clustered index and the clustered index?
By which priority? (the aggregate? The order? The where? The join fields?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server, there are several basic considerations:

- the **clustering key** is vitally important, and it should be chosen with care - it should be narrow, unique, static and possibly ever-increasing (the *NUSE* principle) - see Kim Tripp's [Ever-increasing clustering key - the Clustered Index Debate..........again!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx) blog post for more detailed information on why those characteristics are important).

  So your clustering key should be narrow - 4-byte INT is ideal, it should be **UNIQUE** and static, and this is perfectly handled by some kind of an `ID` - especially if it's an `INT IDENTITY`. GUID is significantly worse, variable-width VARCHAR fields are absolutely out of the question
- every **foreign key column** in a child table referencing a parent table should be part of a nonclustered index. This significantly speeds up JOINs and other operations
- any column used in a `WHERE` or `ORDER BY` clause also is a good index candidate.

But mind you: **indexing is an art** and a balancing act. Each additional index adds more overhead - don't overdo your indices! Less is often more. Try to

- pick a **good** clustering key
- put nonclustered indexes on each of your foreign key columns

and then see if your app performs OK. If it does - fine, let it be. If not: try to isolate the offending queries, and try to tune those. Don't over-do your indexing by tuning each individual query - an index that might benefit one query can severely impact another one. It's a matter of finding the best set of indices for your entire application.

Read Kim Tripp's blog posts - all if you have the time. She's the *Queen of Indexing* and offers tons of very valuable insights into what to do (and what not to do).